# Would MongoDB be a good idea for a social network site (developed in Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, social-networking, nosql

My project (in Ruby on Rails 3) is to develop a "social network" site with the following features:

- Users can be friends. It's mutual friendships; not asymetric like Twitter.
- Users can publish links, to share them. Friends of a user can see what this user has shared.
- Friends can comment on those shared links.

So basically we have Users, Links, and Comments, and all that is connected. An interesting thing in social networks is that the User table has kind of a many-to-many relation with itself.

I think I can handle that level of complexity with SQL and RoR.

My question is: would it be a good idea to use MongoDB (or CouchDB) for such a site?

To be honest, I think the answer is no. MongoDB doesn't seem to fit really well with many-to-many relationships. I can't think of a good MongoDB way to implement the friendship relationships. And I've read that Diaspora started with MongoDB but then switched back to classic SQL.

But some articles on the web defend MongoDB for social networks, and above all I want to make a well-informed decision, and not miss a really cool aspect of MongoDB that would change my life.

Also, I've heard about graph DB, which are probably great, but they really seem too young to me, and I don't know how they'd fit with RoR (and not mentioning heroku).

So, am I missing something?

Comment: This might help you choose: http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems

Comment: @JimmyCuadra : I must say I didn't really understand the schema. I guess I haven't been enough into databases to really understand what's at stake on the 3 sides of that triangle. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like MongoDB and use it a lot, but I am of the opinion that if you are dealing with relational data, you should use the right tool for it. We have relational databases for that. Mongo and Couch are document stores.

Mongo has a serious disadvantage if you are going to be maintaining a lot of inter-document links.  Writes are only guaranteed to be atomic for one document. So you could have inconsistent updates for relations if you are not careful with your schema.

The good thing about MongoDB is that it is very good at scaling.  You can shard and create replica sets.  Foursquare currently uses MongoDB and it has been working pretty well for them.  MongoDB also does map-reduce and has decent geospatial integration.   The team that develops MongoDB is excellent, and I live in NY where they are based and have met them.  You probably are not going to have scaling issues though I would think starting out.

As far as Diaspora switching... I would not want to follow anything they are doing :)

Your comment about graph dbs is interesting though.  I would probably not use a graph DB as my primary DB either, but when dealing with relationships, you can do amazing things with them. In fact usually the demo the guys from graph DB companies will give you is extracting relationship knowledge from a social network. However, there is nothing preventing you from playing with these in the future for network analysis.

In conclusion, when you are starting out here, you are not running into the problems of massive scale yet, and are probably limited on time and money.  Keep in mind that even Facebook does not use just one technology, they have basically expanded to NoSQL for certain functionality (like Facebook messaging).  There is nothing stopping you in the future from using say Mongo and gridFS for handling image uploads or geo-location etc.  It is good to grow as your needs change. I think your gut feeling that you have an SQL app here is right, and the benefits gained with MongoDB would not be realized for a while.

Comment: thanks. I guess I was a victim of MongoDB's hype... And yes, I also have the feeling that an idea would be to use for each functionality the DB that fits its purpose the best (was that English?). But I'm afraid it would create a mess. Anyway, for the core functionalities of my project I'll stick to one DB solution and that's SQL. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: also, out of curiosity, why such a cutting remark on Diaspora? I haven't followed their story

Comment: @arthur in September they came out with some code that indicated they have no idea what they were doing.  There were major security problems that even a novice programmer would know about. Some defended it as they were releasing alpha software, but if you make a delete controller and do not check for authroization (IE anyone signed in can delete any account) there is something wrong. (that was one of many probs) http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/09/22/security-lessons-learned-from-the-diaspora-launch/ sums it up nicely.

Comment: @MichaelPapile I think data modeling and security are two fairly different domains. One of the Diaspora developers has written a thoughtful article about why mongodb was a bad fit for them: http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/.

Comment: @mehaase I agree with a lot of things that was said in that blog post but that is due to the fact that they could not see that their data was not suitable for a document store. A lot of people had that problem but used mongo due to it being marketed as an all purpose database when really it is not. I stand by the statement that I think the Diaspora programmers did not know what they were doing 2 years ago. They probably learned since. I know they are different domains but I would expect a developer to have very basic knowledge of both.

Comment: hey @MichaelPapile mongo 4 has ACID transaction now and i was hoping if you could tell me if i should use mongo or not based current situations.

Answer (score 12):

My advice would be to use whatever you're most familiar with so that you can get up and running quickly. From your question it sounds like that would be SQL rather than MongoDB.

Comment: On a second thought, though: thinking like that, you never learn new stuffs!

Comment: True but it depends on your goal. Is your goal to learn new things or to complete a project? It sounds your goal is the latter, which is why I recommended using what you know. On the other hand if your goal is to learn a new technology, then by all means play around with MongoDB.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting possibility for this is [Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/). It is a cross between a key-value store and a graph database. The userID could be your key and comments and links could be stored in your value. But Riak also has key-to-key [linking](http://wiki.basho.com/Links.html). This could be used for connecting up your users as friends. The linking is asymmetric so you would need to deal with adding and deleting in both directions, but that shouldn't be too hard.

But note that Riak is not a document datastore, which means it is value-agnostic, which means it won't help you extract internal parts of your value, which means if you want to pull a comment out you'll need to first retrieve every comment and link that's stored with the user.

You may also want to check out other graph databases. Social graphs are the prototypical use-case for a graph database.

Comment: Sean Cribbs has created great Ruby client for Riak called Ripple. http://seancribbs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you got to start learning about graphs. Use graph databases that spits out data in JSON format & write it to your Mongodb database.You are dealing with a network , which means there must be a graph of some sort that will allow you to create an ego(user, for example) or focal point or logical center, which is connected to other nodes around it.Nodes could be properties of a particular user such as name, likes,friends, pictures etc. An ego graph would resemble a hub and spokes if you were to draw it.

For further reading, you can refer to how Facebook implemented it's Graph API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/

Here is an attempt to connect Mongodb and Neo4j graph database - https://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/